# Accessing attributes of a nested_resource in a fields_for :collection form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `Assignment` model, which `has_many` `Grade` objects. I'm trying to create a form wherein the user can edit many Grade objects at once, via the Assignment they `belongs_to`. (`Grade` has a `:grade` attribute as well)

```
= form_for @assignment do |f|
  = f.fields_for :grades do |g|
    = g.text_field :grade, class: 'input'
  = f.submit 'Submit', class: 'button is-primary'
```

However, I would like to **access the attributes** of each `Grade` object as it's being iterated over. For example, I would like to know the name of the `Student` that the `Grade` `belongs_to`, so that I can label each input with it. How would I do that?

Comment: Assuming Student is a model and grade belongs_to student, then try `<%= g.object.student.name %>`

Comment: That does it, thanks!

Comment: I will add it asn answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Student` is a model and `Grade` has `belongs_to` with `Student`, then you can do

```
<%= g.object.student.name %>
```